# trying to push a local project to a git repo for the first time, getting weird behavior

Tags: git

I've been trying to piece together the proper way to push a local project to an existing github repo for the first time.  git bash is telling me that "remote origin already exists" so that part appears to be taken care of

"git status" tells me "nothing to commit, working tree clean" so consequently "git add ." most likely isn't adding any files to push to the repo.  I previously ran "git init" on the project parent directory and consequently a top-level ".git" folder exists at the top.  I also previously generated an ssh key for my local machine and wired that up to my github account

So I'm unclear on what I may be missing with this setup/configuration which is preventing me from being able to push my local project files to my github repo.  Any suggestions on what I might be missing here?

===UPDATE===

I followed the steps in error404's comment below.  When I execute the following command:

```
git commit -m 'adding all project files'
```

git bash console writes out all of the file names that were added to the console:

> "84 files changed, 20342 insertions(+)"

However, the when I execute "git push origin master", the console writes out:

> remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository
>   'https://github.com/MyGitHubUserName/MyRepoName.git/' not found

Although I'm able to put that url in the address bar and navigate to the .git address successfully.  And I successfully used the exact same url at the end of my earlier "git remote add origin" command.  Any idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: I would suggest to do `rm -rf .git` then run `git init` again. `git remote add origin <url>`. 
`git add .` `git push origin master`

Comment: Do you want to push the current subfolder only or the whole parent folder?

Answer (score 0):

It may be the easiest to clone the `github` repo to a new folder, create a new branch (if needed), copy your new project into that branch, commit, and push.